# Where is BoneCP documentation?

Tags: bonecp

BoneCP has a very interesting list of features. A look at Javadoc reveals many tweakable parameters. But there seems to be very little documentation on what those parameters actually do or how to configure BoneCP.

For instance, I discovered `bonecp-config.xml` or `maxIdleTime` somewhere in forums when I googled for something else.

Is there a systematic documentation somewhere that I just am too blind to see?

Comment: Did you find any documentation?

Comment: @StephaneGrenier Not really. Only what's on the site and in the blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docs are a little weak right now, but really apart from the config there's little to look into. Have a look here:
http://jolbox.com/bonecp/downloads/site/apidocs/index.html?com/jolbox/bonecp/BoneCPConfig.html

Comment: Can anyone point it out how to configure BoneCP in JBoss 6/7?